# Placeholder for textfield problem in ios 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in a table custom cell.I had set TextField text alignment to UITextAlignmentCenter.I have also added placehoder text to this textField & made this textField firstResponder .Now , what happens is in ios 3.0 & 4.0 , it works perfectlty (cursor blinks in the center & text entered is also in the center)
But in ios 4.2.1, cursor blinks in the left, while the text entered  is always center aligned.If I remove placeholder text, even in ios 4.2.1 everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion regarding the issue:

```
   If you notice the cursor position in prior versions(iOS 4.0 and 4.1),   
you can notice that the cursor is not placed exactly at the center of the
placeholder text. But in 4.2 the cursor is placed neatly at the left side of 
the placeholder.
```

Have a look at the following screen shots.

Cursor position in prior versions (iOS 4.0 and 4.1):

[image]

Cursor position in iOS 4.2:

[image]

If we notice the cursor position is improved in 4.2 and it looks better than the older versions.

```
I guess Apple has made this intentionally to make it better.
```

Comment: Fine, but if an app is in the app store, users may report bug in the app because even in the ios 4.2 cursor should be in the center

Comment: Yes. At first users may expect the cursor to be in center in iOS 4.2 too. But they will feel this change is better, if they are used to it.

Comment: you are perfectly correct.But my requirement is for center align  even in 4.2.If i remove placeholder text , I am able to get center align cursor blink.But I want cursor blink in center & placeholder text as well.Please help me in that direction

Comment: Sorry man.. I don't think I have enough knowledge in this regard to help you.. Sure I will post you if I find a solution.. Meanwhile someone else may help you.. Cheers man!!